# C Language: void *x = &x compiles and runs without declaring x beforehand

Tags: c, void-pointers

The mistake in this snippet, defining a void pointer and initializing it by <s>dereferencing</s> taking the address of the void pointer variable, caused wrong values to be returned, but it compiles and runs without any errors. `bbb` and `aaa` were not declared beforehand. Is there like a switch that can expose this type error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void *bbb = &bbb;

void func(void) {
    void *aaa = &aaa;
    printf("Test aaa %p\n", aaa);
    printf("Test bbb %p\n", bbb);
}

int main()
{
    func();
    return 0;
}

/* Commands used to compile
clang void_pointer1.c -Wall -o void_pointer1
-or-
gcc void_pointer1.c -Wall -o void_pointer1
./void_pointer1 
*/
```

Comment: What do you expect to fail?

Comment: Note: the pointer is never dereferenced.

Comment: @CrisLuengo because OP says "defining a void pointer by dereferencing the void pointer variable", and that mischaracterizes what happens here.

Comment: You could even dereference the pointer (after casting it to something else than `void*`, an integer type corresponding to the pointer size on your machine, for example). It's just a pointer that happens to point to itself. There's nothing wrong with this code except that it is not very useful.

Comment: How do you determine that the values printed are 'wrong'?  What you've got is legitimate but not very useful code.  The value in `aaa` tells you something about the address range where local variables are stored; the value in `bbb` tells you something about the address range where global variables are stored; but that's about all (and the 'something' is not very precise, portable, or generally usable).

Comment: This would trigger a warning for any pointer other than `void*`, since you cannot implicitly convert X** to X* for any type `X` other than `void`. Using `void*` variables is a signal that you are about to do something behind the compiler's back and you want it to assume you know what you are doing. `void*` parameters are sometimes unavoidable, but `void*` variables can (and should imho) usually be replaced with typed variables.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The void *x = &x was a typo. It should have been void *x = &s. I was hoping to find a way to have the compiler expose where I might make the mistake in the future.

Comment: @rici I agree with all you say and value your corollary with doing something behind the compiler's back. Except I don't understand why void* is related to X** indicating a pointer to pointer.

Comment: @buoy: you can implicitly convert `void**` to `void*` because you can implicitly convert any pointer to `void*`. But for any type `X` other than `void` , the conversion from `X**` to `X*` is not valid. The declaration `X* foo = &foo;` requires the implicit conversion of a value of type `X**` (`&foo`) to type `X*` (`foo`), which is only possible if `X` is `void`. So it is the use of `void* x` which makes the typo hard to detect.

Comment: @rici: I think you are correct that this initialization is not valid for any pointer type other than `void *` (optionally qualified), but it is legal for at least one other type; you can do `_Bool t = &t;`. 

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I don't see how that is relevant to this discussion, but in any case both gcc and clang do issue the warning (with `-Wall`) that the "address of 't' will always evaluate to 'true'". Although I can't help thinking that `_Bool t = &t;` is a less likely typo than `void *t = &t;`. The intent would have to have been something like `_Bool* t = &x;`, which is two mistakes (missing `*` and incorrect variable name). Of course, the "address always evaluates to true" warning applies to a lot of other typos, which are more common (at least, I've triggered it a couple of time.)...

Comment: ... As you yourself point out somewhere, most compilers do warn about semantically legal expressions which are unlikely to be correct (`if (a = b)`, for example). But as I said, `void*` is normally a signal that the programmer thinks they know what they are doing. (Even then, I wouldn't have been surprised if it had triggered a warning. Perhaps a feature request is in order.)

Comment: @rici: Compilers should not warn about any code decorated with “ ”.

Answer (score 4):

It's a logical error, not a syntactic error, and consequently the compiler cannot expose it.

`bbb` is a variable that contains a pointer to void. This variable has an address. You can get this address by `&bbb`. This address (a `void **` value) implicitly converts to `void*`, and can be assigned to the variable `bbb`.

Comment: "bbb is a variable that contains a pointer to void." I understand this is the result of void *bbb=&bbb. I was surprised that apparently the compiler works on the left and defines bbb as a pointer then works on the right and uses that same bbb just defined on the left. I didn't need to declare bbb beforehand.

Comment: @Buoy Well, if you want to assign something to `bbb`, then `bbb` must already be declared by necessity.

Comment: @Buoy: I am not positive about the details of the C standard on this, but, per clause 6.7.6 of C 2011, the text `void *bbb` is a *declarator*, and it declares `bbb`. Per clause 6.7.9, `= &bbb` is an *initializer*. Together, they make up an *init-declarator*, and, with the `;`, they form a *declaration*. But the standard does not say that the *declaration* is what declares the identifier. It says the *declarator* does that. So, by the time we reach the `=`, `bbb` is already declared.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: It is not strictly correct to say the compiler cannot expose this error because it is logical and not syntactic. `if (a = b)` is not a syntax error, but the compiler advises me about it. Since Apple clang does not warn about this even with `-Wall` (and Apple’s compiler developers are pretty aggressive about warnings), likely it either has some valid use or is a rarely made mistake.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you make a good point. I'd guess it's an uncommon mistake, or easy to spot reading code, unlike the equal sign in the if statement. On the other hand, the equal sign in the if statement can be correct syntax, but if intentional is meant to obfuscate; it's always a bad idea to use it.

Answer (score -1):

Address of the variable is known during the  compile time. So there is no problem to assign it the pointer with the address of itself.

Two cases:

global or static pointer - the actual address is calculated during the linking. 
local variables - the address is known as the offset from the stack pointer.

Comment: *"Address of the variable is known during the compile time"*, it's not, at least for automatic variables.

Comment: Your second paragraph is closer to the truth, but it is not correct either. Some modern loaders use address space layout randomization, so the addresses of various parts of the program are different in different runs of the program, and they are not known at link time. **Some** information about addresses is known at compile time or link time, such as how far some objects are relative to certain reference locations. But this is not what enables `&bbb` to be used. Even if **nothing** about the address of `bbb` is known at compile time, it is possible to take its address at run time.

Comment: @EricPostpischil no.The loader changes the revelant position in memory as it is in the relocation table - ie sets the actual address in the DATA segment,. From the compiler point of view the address is known. From the programmer point of view as well.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - it is as during the compilation the variable has the known offset from the  stack pointer.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: You are saying the address is in the relocation table but the loader changes it? If the loader changes the address at load time (by an amount not known at compile time), then the sentence “Address of the variable is known during the compile time” is false.

Comment: @EricPostpischil of course is known. If the system allows program execution in the different addresses all non relative addresses are relocated,. Do you think that the jumps calls and another operations are unknown? Program jumps to the random addresses. It is ridiculous. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)

Comment: @PeterJ_01: Jumps are executed using addresses calculated at load or execution time. So they have nothing to do with whether the addresses are known at compile time. As I have written, **some information** about addresses may be known at compile time. But **the final resolved absolute address** is not known at compile time (for normal objects in typical C implementations). I am sorry, but your English is not good. Your sentence “If the system allows program execution in the different addresses all non relative addresses are relocated” is contorted and unclear…

Comment: … A non-relative address is absolute, and absolute addresses are not relocated. Absolute addresses are fixed. Relative addresses are relocated—they are called “relative” because the actual location of a relative address is relative to some reference point, so it is adjusted when the reference point is finally set. And the phrase “program execution in the different addresses” does not make sense.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil but it dows not make any difference for the compliler & programmer, Your point is just wrong. For me it is EOD.